# Why is Xcode saying "UTF8Encoding undeclared"?

Tags: ios, xcode, utf-8

When compiling the statement below, Xcode is giving me an error saying UTF8Encoding is undeclared...

```
  NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:stringData encoding:UTF8Encoding];
```

Why?

Thanks!

Comment: The example code you cut and paste before was wrong :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as far is i know it should be `NSUTF8StringEncoding`

Comment: yeah, that fixed it, thanks!  weird, tho, i selected it from the auto-completion list.  oh well.

Comment: another reason (besides speed) to disable autocompletion in xcode ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try NSUTF8StringEncoding.

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:stringData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```